CORS blocking data from going from front end to back end
I'm new in web development , I'm trying to make an app to administer medical records using spring boot in the backend and reactjs in the frontend. I created all the necessary code in the backend and in the frontend but I really can't make the link between them. Needless to say that as a beginner who is pressured by time , all the code in here is made out of research .here is the code I wrote for the CORS configuration
package com.firstapp.Fullstack.app_backend.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class webConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}

and here is the code snipper I wrote for the front end part of the link:
  const nextStep = () => setStep(step + 1);
  const prevStep = () => setStep(step - 1);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/Document', formData);
      console.log('Form submitted successfully', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting form', error);
    }
  };

I always receive the same problem when trying to send data from front to backend.
I tried ever single variant of code possible , I even tried changing web browsers (very dumb i know) but I'm always met with the same problem.

Try this :
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CORSConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}

